# embeber imagen a HTML con python

Tags: html, python, json

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña web con Python y Flask. Me topé con un pequeño conflicto, la web es para un evento de desarrolladores que habrá en la empresa y cuenta con un apartado de registro y otro de proyectos, en donde se muestran todos los proyectos que ya aprobamos, y en la parte de registro son todos los datos del equipo. El dato que me causa conflicto es la imagen debido a que cuando lo subo hago lo siguiente:

```
# leemos la imagen
    with open(picture, 'rb') as f:
        binary_data = f.read()
```

como el comentario lo dice, leo la imagen con python mediante ese código y lo convierte a un archivo binario, entonces una vez teniendo el archivo en la variable binary_data simplemente lo subo a la BD en un dato de tipo BLOB. Ahora, cuando lo quiero mostrar en la web hago lo siguiente:

```
tags=[]
logo_sql = "select PROJECT_ID, LOGO from Engine1.PROJECT WHERE ACCEPTED = '1'"
stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn,logo_sql)

pictures = {}
row = ibm_db.fetch_assoc(stmt)
while(row):
    pictures[row['PROJECT_ID']] = row['LOGO'].encode('base64').replace('\n', '')
    img_tag = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,%s">' %pictures[row['PROJECT_ID']]

    tags.append(img_tag)

    row = ibm_db.fetch_assoc(stmt)


return render_template('site.html', catego=catego, tags = tags)
```

tags [] es una lista que contendrá las etiquetas de imagen, el query me saca los datos tipo BLOB, que en este caso es la imagen que subí anteriormente y mediante un ejemplo que encontré en internet para enbeber una imagen en HTML directo desde python, creo una etiqueta con el ID de cada uno de los proyectos, y en el while creo tantos como sean necesarios. El problema es aquí, cuando quiero mandar esos datos en el render_template hacía HTML, htlm no lo comprende y me lo muestra de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y vemos que no lo interpreta, solo lo muestra en texto plano, ¿alguien que pueda ayudarme a que se muestre la imagen y no el data?.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero de todo es que no sé si utilizas Python 2 ó 3. La codificación puede ser lógicamente diferente según la versión. Te puedo ayudar con python 3. Así, una posible solución sería primero importando la librería base64:

```
import base64
```

Luego, dentro del **while** sustituir la primera línea por la siguiente:

```
pictures[row['PROJECT_ID']] = base64.encodestring(row['LOGO'])
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda.